# Control strip led 24v TM1814

Tags: led, mosfet

I would like to control a rgbw [image: led tm1814]led strip of hundreds of meters (due to its length, I need to work with 24v).
I'm thinking of buying these TM1814 LEDs, which can be cut every 6 LEDs/10cm and have a consumption of 18W per metre. I will have to cut them every 6 leds and place each single strip at a distance of one meter from the previous one (so I will use 10 meters to illuminate a length of 100 metres).
but now I need to understand how to create the circuit: raspberry pi4- 10m strip led tm1814 24v 180w- breadboard- 24v 200w power supply.
I can't figure out how to connect the 24V, GND and DIN pins of the led strip. can i use mosfets?
do i have to power the raspberry with another power supply? do i need transformers or relays?
If you could draw me a picture it would help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: not a question about the Raspberry Pi